# Reading application.yml in service

Tags: java, spring

I have a oracle rest end point, and I read the entries from there. 
This is my application.yml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
oracleUrl: https://cloud-url/filter_by/login_id/
```

OracleProperties

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class OracleProperties {

    @Value("${oracleUrl}")
    String oracleUrl;

    public String getOracleUrl() {
        return oracleUrl;
    }

    public void setOracleUrl(String oracleUrl) {
        this.oracleUrl = oracleUrl;
    }
}
```

Application.java

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties({OracleProperties.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Service

```
@Autowired
private OracleProperties oracleProperties;

String oracleUrl = oracleProperties.getOracleUrl();
```

My oracleUrl is null, Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: You can't use the `new` operator to load Spring Objects. If you do so then you wont get dependency injection, hence your values will be null.

Comment: I changed to Autowired and updated the question, But I see null pointer exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `@Configuration` annotation on `OracleProperties`. The `@ConfigurationProperties("oracle")` will pick up any properties with prefix `oracle`. Helps to group a family of properties with `oracle` prefix. Also Notice, there is no `@Value` on top of `url` attribute.

```
@ConfigurationProperties("oracle")
public class OracleProperties {

    private String url;

    public String getUrl() {
        return oracleUrl;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

Changes to your `application.yml`,

```
oracle:
  url: https://cloud-url/filter_by/login_id/
```

Comment: Thanks , my mistake, moved the oracleProperties.getOracleUrl(); inside the method.its working now.